# Python heatmap with Hierarchical clustering TypeError: dendrogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color_list'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

I am using python seaborn for `heatmap` plotting with hierarchical clustering.
   Here is what I tried,

```
import pandas as pd, seaborn as sns
import scipy.spatial as sp, scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hc
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
sns.set(font="monospace")

iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
DF = pd.DataFrame(X, index = ["iris_%d" % (i) for i in range(X.shape[0])], columns = iris.feature_names)

DF_corr = DF.T.corr()
DF_dism = 1 - DF_corr   # distance matrix
linkage = hc.linkage(sp.distance.squareform(DF_dism), method='average')
sns.clustermap(DF_dism, row_linkage=linkage, col_linkage=linkage)
```

And its throwing following error, I am pasting the traceback
 TypeError: dendrogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color_list'

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-4da2c090d592> in <module>()
     11 DF_dism = 1 - DF_corr   # distance matrix
     12 linkage = hc.linkage(sp.distance.squareform(DF_dism), method='average')
---> 13 sns.clustermap(DF_dism, row_linkage=linkage, col_linkage=linkage)

/home/alva/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py in clustermap(data, pivot_kws, method, metric, z_score, standard_scale, figsize, cbar_kws, row_cluster, col_cluster, row_linkage, col_linkage, row_colors, col_colors, mask, **kwargs)
   1137                         row_cluster=row_cluster, col_cluster=col_cluster,
   1138                         row_linkage=row_linkage, col_linkage=col_linkage,
-> 1139                         **kwargs)

/home/alva/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py in plot(self, metric, method, colorbar_kws, row_cluster, col_cluster, row_linkage, col_linkage, **kws)
    976         colorbar_kws = {} if colorbar_kws is None else colorbar_kws
    977         self.plot_dendrograms(row_cluster, col_cluster, metric, method,
--> 978                               row_linkage=row_linkage, col_linkage=col_linkage)
    979         try:
    980             xind = self.dendrogram_col.reordered_ind

/home/alva/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py in plot_dendrograms(self, row_cluster, col_cluster, metric, method, row_linkage, col_linkage)
    901             self.dendrogram_row = dendrogram(
    902                 self.data2d, metric=metric, method=method, label=False, axis=0,
--> 903                 ax=self.ax_row_dendrogram, rotate=True, linkage=row_linkage)
    904         else:
    905             self.ax_row_dendrogram.set_xticks([])

/home/alva/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py in dendrogram(data, linkage, axis, label, metric, method, rotate, ax)
    652     plotter = _DendrogramPlotter(data, linkage=linkage, axis=axis,
    653                                  metric=metric, method=method,
--> 654                                  label=label, rotate=rotate)
    655     if ax is None:
    656         ax = plt.gca()

/home/alva/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py in __init__(self, data, linkage, metric, method, axis, label, rotate)
    483         else:
    484             self.linkage = linkage
--> 485         self.dendrogram = self.calculate_dendrogram()
    486 
    487         # Dendrogram ends are always at multiples of 5, who knows why

/home/alva/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py in calculate_dendrogram(self)
    568         """
    569         return hierarchy.dendrogram(self.linkage, no_plot=True,
--> 570                                     color_list=['k'], color_threshold=-np.inf)
    571 
    572     @property
```

Any support or suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: Try to upgrade your `scipy` to a more recent version. The argument `color_list` was removed in the recent `0.18.1` version - [_look here_](https://github.com/rgommers/scipy/commit/4e7d2410d7d8f03eb1f014d12418836b761fcd62)

Comment: I have the same problem and I have updated scipy to the version 0.18.1. @NickilMaveli do you have any other suggestions? a solution has been found?

Comment: @NickilMaveli, thanks for the suggestion it helped :)